# pyspark partition and batch data for api call

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to do the following task and I'm wondering if this the most efficient way to do so in PySpark

sample data:
|     email     |     balance   |
|---------------------|------------------|
|             js@google.com      |         34       |
|         ab@yahoo.com        |         42       |

The problem I'm trying to solve is to send data to a third party via post request. My solution is:

1. df.repartition(5) // 5 is the max number of concurrent calls
2. foreachPartition(batch_func) divide each partition into batches of 200 records  // max 200 records per call

   - ```
     def batch_func(iterator):
       batch = [x for x in itertools.islice(iterator, 200)]
       while len(batch) > 0:
           yield batch
           batch = [x for x in itertools.islice(iterator, 200)]
     ```
3. each call needs to be in the following format:

```
payload = { "action": "createOrUpdate", 
            "dedupeBy": some_input_field, 
            "input": [{"email":"js@google.com", "money": 34}, {"email": "ab@yahoo.com ", "money": 42}]
}

basically I want to make numOfPartitions API calls in parallel and make the API calls within each partition sequentially (the input to each API call is a batch)

Does anyone have any advice on how to achieve this?

Thanks!
```